# Can a multi meter measure a potential static discharge?

Tags: grounding, multimeter, electrostatic

Can a multi meter measure a potential static discharge like between hands and laptop before I open cover and replace a battery? Like if I touch laptop and my hands with the each two probes of a multi meter, is it possible to read a DC potential voltage and determine if it is enough to cause a static discharge? Then we know that if we have to touch ground before touching laptop in the scenario of no static bracelet or failure of it.

Comment: No the impedance is a few orders of magnitude too low at 1M . ESD protected FET buffers are needed in the GOhm range

Comment: But if you touch a 1M DMM between you and the case, any charge difference will decay to zero , just as touching the case will

Comment: 1000v will push 1mA of current through 1 megaohm, so you'll discharge any static charge almost instantly.

Comment: Keeping one hand on case grounds acts like a wrist strap

Comment: I see. So is my understanding correct? If I switch a DMM to measure DC voltage between me and a naked laptop, despite I cannot measure potential, but I will RELATIVELY GENTLY discharge WITHOUT SPARKLE and DAMAGE to PCB? Relatively gently means comparing to sparkle but sill very fast. OR, maybe I will just cause a sparkle between a probe and laptop PCB and burn it?

Comment: `Then we know that if we have to touch ground before touching laptop` ... it makes no sense to be measuring anything ... it is easier to just ground yourself each time

Comment: @Superuser No your understanding is not correct. Static has voltages of kV and travels through materials with tens or hundreds of MegaOhms of resistance. Your multimeter is not made to measure kV of voltage or work with impedances tens or hundreds of MegaOhms of resistance. Wrong tool.

Comment: There are at least three instruments we can use to measuring static: electrostatic field meters, Coulomb meters used with Faraday cups, and non-contacting electrostatic voltmeters. ... The only meter that actually measures charge is the Coulomb meter.

Comment: You should have a properly grounded wrist strap on, that eliminates the problems.